# Can i convert .app file path into NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert my application.app file into NSData and generating hash value. But i am getting nil. Here is my peace of code and correct me where i am wrong.

Note: I am able to get same thing for Info.plist file.

```
NSString *documentdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *appPath = [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"application.app"];
NSData *appPathData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:appPath];
```

Comment: Please give me why it's down voted. then only i come to know what mistake i did.

Comment: Your directory is more than likely incorrect. I have a question for you, for what possible reason would you even want to do this for?

Comment: appPath i am getting proper only.I want to create hash key for .app file. is it possible or not? @Popeye

Comment: For what purpose? I can't see any logical reason or benefit for doing this. Also no I don't think it is possible but I will stand corrected if it is.

Comment: Have you at least checked if any file exists at your `appPath`?

Comment: yes verified it, that condition check haven't post here. i thought here issue is nsdata object is nil.

Comment: Another issue here then is you haven't shared your actual code. Please share all relevant code.

Comment: @Popeye isn't the why beside the point of the question? Could be curiosity, could be a number of legitimate use cases (i.e. checking your executable hash to see if anyone messed with it..)

Comment: @FabioRitrovato it's really not beside the point. If it is purely because they want to know if it can be done then we will not waste our time with it, whereas if it is some that they really need to do then we might spend time helping. Also we might be able to provide a better more efficient approach to the problem. So the **WHY** is always important and should never just be ignored.

Comment: @Popeye so what you're saying is that we shouldn't help people that just want to learn something new but only those that have a practical need... Doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: @FabioRitrovato You will find more people helpful if they know it is going towards something useful and not just wanting to know if it can be done for no purpose what so ever. Either way I have asked a genuine question so if I feel it's not being taken seriously then I will not bother to help. What you need to remember is we don't need to help I'm sure I can find some other question that needs more attention from me, but yet I am here trying to find out more information so I can provide a better more efficient answer, if they don't want that then fine I'll move onto the next question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of thing wrong with your approach...

1. a .app is not a file, but a folder, so what you'll need to do is actually read `[documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"application.app/application"]` to read the actual executable
2. since iOS8 the apps files structure has changed around, so to get to your app you actually need to use
   `[[NSBundle mainBundle].resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"application"]`

Comment: Thanks @Fabio Ritrovato, which one is the binary file?

Comment: yeah i got the logic why i am not able to get the application.app, because it's like a folder not a file. This works for me  : [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"application.app/application"]